# "Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6)" error in model.fit in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I was building a model for a classification problem in keras. However, it is throwing the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError
Traceback (most recent call last) 
 c:\Users\anwes\Downloads\chest_xray.ipynb Cell 15' in <cell line: 7>()
          1 # Training model
          2 # Data -> 18000
          3 # Train + Test + Validation
          4 # Train data + Test Data
          5 # Validation/Test Data -> (0.1*18000) -> 1800
          6 # Train Data -> 18000-1800
    ----> 7 model.fit(X_train, Y_train,epochs=2 ,validation_split=0.1)
    
    File c:\Users\anwes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)

         65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
         66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    ---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
         68 finally:
         69   del filtered_tb
    
    File c:\Users\anwes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         52 try:
         53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
    ---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
         55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
         57   if name is not None: ...
  File "c:\Users\anwes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5238, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
          res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' 

Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6).  Label values: 6 4 9 3 7 9 1 1 8 2 2 1 1 1 3 1 0 0 7 9 9 6 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 8 1 0   [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_765]
```

I am attaching the code for the same:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
import glob
from PIL import Image
import PIL

train_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/anwes/Downloads/archive/chest_xray/train/*/**")
train_files
len(train_files)
from random import shuffle
shuffle(train_files)
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(train_files[691])
im_arr=np.array(im)
plt.imshow(im);


print(im_arr.shape)

X_train = np.zeros((len(train_files), 128, 128))
Y_train = np.zeros((len(train_files), 1))
for i, fi in enumerate(train_files):
    im = Image.open(fi)
    img = Image.open(fi).convert('L')
    resized_im = img.resize((128,128))
    X_train[i,:,:]=np.array(resized_im)
    Y_train[i, :] = fi[-6]
    
X_train = X_train/255.0
X_train
# Sequantial -> Layers - Conv, Dense, 
# Relu , Leaky Relu
model= keras.Sequential([
    # 1
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=120,
    kernel_size=3,
        # filtering out negative values
    activation='relu',
    input_shape=(128,128,1)
    ),
    # 2
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters=24,
    kernel_size=3,
    activation='relu',
    ),
    # 3
    # 1d matrix
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # 4
    # reduction layers
    keras.layers.Dense(
        units=96,
        activation='relu',
    ),
    # 5 
    # 96 units -> 6 units
    keras.layers.Dense(6,activation='softmax') # 0-5 fingers
    
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
X_train=X_train.reshape(len(X_train),128,128,1)
X_train.shape
# Training model
# Data -> 18000
# Train + Test + Validation
# Train data + Test Data
# Validation/Test Data -> (0.1*18000) -> 1800
# Train Data -> 18000-1800
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,epochs=2 ,validation_split=0.1)
```

I searched for a solution on the web and Stack Overflow, but in vain. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the traceback you provided the full traceback? If not, please add the full traceback to the OP.

Comment: The error tells you what the issue is, it seems you are using 10 labels in your dataset (numbers 0 through 9) whereas the output layer of your network only uses 6 nodes. Simply make sure that the number of nodes in your last layer matches the number of classes you have.